# How to break a long environment variable text into multiple lines in dotenv file (for docker-compose)

Tags: docker-compose, dotenv

I have a regular `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  test_service:
    image: some_img:0.1.0
    ...
    ...
    env_file: 
      - .env
    ...
    ...
```

here, I am loading environment variables using a `.env` file. In the file I have an environment variable with a long string value.

```
# .env
SPACE=test
SPECIFICS=packageA,packageB,packageC,packageD,...
```

I want `SPECIFICS` to parsed as above(`SPECIFICS=packageA,packageB,packageC,packageD,...` ) but would like to break it down into multiple lines for easy reading, may be like below (with or without indentation)

```
SPECIFICS=packageA,
          packageB,
          packageC,
          packageD,
          ...
```

I do not want to use `environment:` section in `docker-compose.yml` because I am loading quite a few environment variables which will bloat the corresponding section.

Can anyone suggest a solution for this

CHeers,
DD.